# How does Java 8 time api choose the offset on DST change period

Tags: java, java-time

In Java 8 time API, you can create a LocalDateTime which falls in the overlap of time during the DST time change in autumn (Central European Time).

You can convert this to a ZonedDateTime which represents a precise moment in time using a ZoneId.

Doing this does not actually resolve the ambiguity - there could still be two moments in time which correspond to this LocalDateTime and this Zone (but at different offsets).

How and why (reference welcome) does the time API choose the summer offset?

```
@Test
public void TimeSetOnDST() throws Exception {
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 10, 30, 2, 30); // in the DST time overlap
    ZonedDateTime of = ZonedDateTime.of(time, ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich"));
    System.out.println(of); // 2016-10-30T02:30+02:00[Europe/Zurich]
    // But why not 2016-10-30T02:30+01:00[Europe/Zurich] ?
    // Is this just "by convention"?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's well documented in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneId-):

> In most cases, there is only one valid offset for a local date-time. In the case of an overlap, when clocks are set back, there are two valid offsets. This method uses the earlier offset typically corresponding to "summer".

As described in the comments by @JodaStephen, if you want to choose the other available offset, you can use [the `withLaterOffsetAtOverlap` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withLaterOffsetAtOverlap--).

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is just by convention then.

Comment: Simply use [`withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withLaterOffsetAtOverlap--) if you want to change the convention. (A convention was chosen as it is better than an exception or an additional parameter for most use cases.)

Comment: I feel that convention wisely selected. `LocalDateTime` doc says it's a "wall clock", and the convention follows what we all assume when we wake up the morning after DST shift :)

Comment: Also i admire the sustained reengineering of an already over engineered time/date support. Well at least in comparison with other language's SDKs which generally feel accomplished by just wrapping the POSIX time API.